# GetReservation returning Viewership is restricted for the PNR

Tags: sabre

I'm currently using the sabre web service TravelItineraryReadLLSRQ (version 2.2.0) and I can successfully retrieve all on the PNR data. Now I'm trying to implement GetReservation but I'm getting the error below.

Not finding any further detail from the dev sabre portal - has anybody seen this and know what the 'fix' is?

"Viewership is restricted for the PNR, caused by [Viewership is restricted for the PNR (Unsupported security check), code: 700102, severity: MODERATE]"

```
<GetReservationRS xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Errors xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18">
    <Error>
      <Code>700102</Code>
      <Message>Viewership is restricted for the PNR, caused by [Viewership is restricted for the PNR (Unsupported security check), code: 700102, severity: MODERATE]</Message>
      <Severity>MODERATE</Severity>
    </Error>
  </Errors>
</GetReservationRS>
```

Comment: I should have included the RQ in case that matters ...

 <GetReservationRQ xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="1.18.0">
   <Locator xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18">XXZRIM</Locator>
   <RequestType xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18">Stateless</RequestType>
   <ReturnOptions xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18">
  <SubjectAreas>
    <SubjectArea>FULL</SubjectArea>
  </SubjectAreas>
   </ReturnOptions>
 </GetReservationRQ>

Comment: When i use "stateful" it gives error "ATK not supported" but if i use "stateless" is gives PNR restricted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to try using "Stateful" since "Stateless" is only intended for airline customers. You can use Stateful together with a locator or without it, makes no difference.

You may also may want to be aware that the service can be called with the Full, Default and Simple View Names. Only Simple will return more updated data which you can obtain by using the required subject areas in the payload. Full and Default will ignore the subject areas you use.

Comment: Using "Stateful" instead of "Stateless" was the key - it now returns data. Thanks for the tip.